# angle between two vectors-given in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let 
$u=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1&a&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}:a\epsilon R\right\}$

$v=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a&0&0\\0&a&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}:a\epsilon R\right\}$

Then what is the angle between these two?

here $u=\begin{pmatrix} 1+a\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and  $v=\begin{pmatrix} a\\a\\0\end{pmatrix}$
after that how to proceed..not getting the correct answer.
please may i know the answer?

Comment: Multiply out the matrix and vectors. What do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $u\cdot v = \|u\| \|v\|\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$

We have $u\cdot v = (1+a)a + a = a^2 + 2a$, $\|u\|^2 = (1+a)^2 + 1$ and $\|v\|^2 = 2a^2$, thus $\cos\theta = \dfrac{a^2 + 2a}{\sqrt{((1+a)^2 + 1)(2a^2)}}$, then solve it for $\theta$

Now we have $\cos\theta = \dfrac{a^2 + 2a}{\sqrt{2(a^2 + 2a + 2)}|a|}$. For a given value of $a$, we can compute the value of RHS, say $\dfrac{a^2 + 2a}{\sqrt{2(a^2 + 2a + 2)}|a|} = b$, then $\theta = \arccos(b)$, where $\arccos$ is the inverse function of $\cos$

Comment: still dint get the answer..

Comment: @amit I edited, hope now it's clear

Comment: ya i got it till here.hoe to simplfy denominator part.

Comment: @amit Yeah, you are on the right way

Comment: what is the answer..??

Comment: @amit If you have difficulty when simplifying, write a bit more details I am happy to explain. But sorry I can't do all for you.

Comment: now how to get the answer

Comment: @amit I edited. If your know the function $\arccos$, then I think it's quite direct.

Comment: no i dint get how will calculate it?

Comment: @amit there is no direct way to compute it, except for special  values, usually we use a calculator, or make some approximation

Comment: we can take it ..$\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}$..then will get as pi/4

Comment: @ami yeah, for some corresponding value of $a$